# What is the error in this time conversion code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have to convert time in 12hour format into 24 hour format. Input is given as a single line  string ( 12:45:00AM ===>  00:45:00 ). This code doesn't give an output, but the error cannot be seen.

```
def timeString(hh,mm,ss)
    hh.to_s.rjust(2,"0") + ":" + mm.to_s.rjust(2, "0") + ":" + ss.to_s.rjust(2, "0")
end

def timeConversion(s)
    hh = s[0,2].to_i
    mm = s[3,2].to_i
    ss = s[6,2].to_i

    if s[8]==?A
        if hh==12
            hh =0
            t =timeString(hh,mm,ss)
            return t
        elsif hh < 12
            t = timeString(hh,mm,ss)
            return t
        end 
    elsif s[8] == ?P
        if hh == 12
            t = timeString(hh,mm,ss)
            return t
        elsif hh >12
            hh -=12
            t = timeString(hh,mm,ss)
            return t
        end
    end 

end

s = gets.chomp  
result = timeConversion s  
print result
```

Comment: Thanks . I found the error.    '   elsif hh >12  '  cannot be there. and hh-=12 is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found the problem I'll suggest an alternative way of writing your method.

```
def convert_12_to_24(s12)
  hr = s12[0,2].to_i
  hr = if s12[-2,2] == 'AM'
         hr == 12 ? 0 : hr
       else
         hr == 12 ? 12 : hr + 12
       end
  "%02d%s" % [hr, s12[2..-3]]
end

convert_12_to_24 "12:00:00AM"  #=> "00:00:00"
convert_12_to_24 "12:59:59AM"  #=> "00:59:59"
convert_12_to_24 "01:00:00AM"  #=> "01:00:00"
convert_12_to_24 "11:59:00AM"  #=> "11:59:00"
convert_12_to_24 "12:00:00PM"  #=> "12:00:00"
convert_12_to_24 "12:59:59PM"  #=> "12:59:59"
convert_12_to_24 "01:00:00PM"  #=> "13:00:00"
convert_12_to_24 "11:59:59PM"  #=> "23:59:59"
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for string formatting directives (here `"%02d%s"`).